# How to validate email in custom rule

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel.

I use the same field for username and email. Additionally the user has to choose, if the input is an username or an email.

If the type is email, i like to add the email validation. If it's username, there is no email validation needed.

I tried to create a custom rule with the if function. But how can i then validate the email?

```
class StoreUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name'            =>      'required',
            'last_name'             =>       'required',
            'password'              =>      'required',
            'email'                 =>      ['required', new ValidateEmailRule()]
        ];
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
class ValidateEmailRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (request()->is_email) {
            //validate email ---here i need help to get the right code---
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {

        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically if the user selects email as an option and then after you want to check if the user inputted value is valid email address format or not right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use `'email' => 'required_if:is_email:1`?

EDIT:

```
$rules = [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
];

    if ($this->is_email) {
        $rules['email'] = 'email';
    }

    return $rules;
```

Comment: If `is_email = 1` i like to check if the input in `email` is a valid email-adress

Comment: EDIT: i mean like this: https://www.codepile.net/pile/eXj4vWKr

Comment: `$this->attributes->get('is_email')` return NULL. I changed it to `if (request()->is_email) {$rules['email'] = 'email';}` and it works

Comment: how about `if ($this->is_email == 1)` or `if ($this->boolean(is_email)`?

Comment: I know, just wanted to update my answer, and using `$this` instead of `request()` looks better imo and I want to be sure it works :)